# Evaluating the error function by integrating $ \mathrm e^{−t^2} $ with Simpson's rule

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

I am trying to evaluate an error function with Simpson's rule because there is no other way to integrate it. The function is

$$
{\rm erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt π}\int_0^x \mathrm e^{−t^2}\, \mathrm dt
$$

and I want the value at 1.

I typed in the code:

```
Simpson[a_, b_, m_] := 
  Module[{}, 
    h = (b - a)/(2 m);
    sum = 0;
    s1 = 0;
    For[k = 1, k <= m - 1, k++, s1 = s1 + f[a + h (2 k - 1)];];]
    s2 = 0 
    For[k = 1, k <= m, k++, s2 = s2 + f[a + h (2 k - 1)];];
    sum = h/3 (f[a] + f[b] + 2 s1 + 4 s2);
    Return[sum]
```

and, of course, an error pops up in my output.

Does anyone know how to fix the error part so I can get a numerical answer?

Comment: There are some serious syntax errors in your code. Also, are you aware that `Erf` is a built-in  function and that `Erf[1] // N` returns 0.842701?

Comment: "...there is no other way to integrate it." Have you seen `NIntegrate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I rewrite your code as

```
simpson[a_, b_, m_] :=
  Module[{f, h, s1, s2, k},
    f[t_] := E^-(t^2);
    h = (b - a)/(2 m);
    s1 = 0;
    For[k = 1, k <= m - 1, k++, s1 = s1 + f[a + h (2 k - 1)]];
    s2 = 0;
    For[k = 1, k <= m, k++, s2 = s2 + f[a + h (2 k - 1)]]; 
    h/3 (f[a] + f[b] + 2 s1 + 4 s2)]
```

then evaluating

```
2 N[simpson[0, 1, 500]]/Sqrt[Pi]
```

gives

> `0.842938`

which is not a bad approximation. As to there being no better way than Simpson's rule,  the built-in function `NIntegrate`, is certainly a better way.

```
Block[{f}, f[t_] := E^-(t^2); 2 NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]/Sqrt[Pi]]
```

gives the much better result

> `0.842701`

Note that the built-in function when evaluated numerically

```
Erf[1] // N
```

gives

> `0.842701`

which matches the `NIntegrate` result up to display precision.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it, you can also use the following version:

```
n = 8;
a = 0;
b = 1;
h = (b - a)/n;
f[t_] := E^-(t^2);

simpson = 
  h/6 Sum[f[a + i h] + 4 f[a + (i + 1/2) h] + f[a + (i + 1) h], {i, 0, n - 1}] // N;

2*simpson/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
0.842701
```

Answer (score 0):

The major point is the list of coefficients `{1, 4, 2, 4, 2, ..., 1}`, which I use a `SparseArray` to realize below. And the final sum can be conceived as the inner product of two vectors, realized by `Dot`:

```
Clear[nIntegrateBySimpson, erfintegrand]

nIntegrateBySimpson[func : (_Function | _Symbol), xrange_, n_Integer] := 
  Module[{simpsoncoefficients, h, subd},
         h = -Subtract @@ xrange/n;
         subd = Subdivide[##, n] & @@ N[xrange];
         simpsoncoefficients = SparseArray[{{1} -> 1., {i_?EvenQ} -> 4., {-1} -> 1.}, 
                                           n + 1, 2.
                               ];
         h/3 simpsoncoefficients.(func /@ subd)
  ]

erfintegrand[t_] := 2/Sqrt[\[Pi]] Exp[-t^2]
```

So, the numerical integral can be obtained by following codes:

```
nIntegrateBySimpson[erfintegrand, {0, 1}, 12]
```

> ```
> 0.842701
> ```

One notices that the range on which the integral is performed need not be divided into too many parts, as shown above, only 12 samples have been collected.